# Program Win/Loss statistics in Number Guessing Game for Python

Tags: python

I've written a program for a Number guessing game in Python which i have almost completed. However, there is one small problem i can't figure out. After the game finishes I want the statistics to be printed out for each player to a .txt with the following information:

**Username | Win or Loss | Number of Guesses.**

I can't figure out how to generate the Win/Loss statistic in the following line for each player:

```
f.write(str(playerName)+ '|' +str(numberOfGuesses)+'\n').
```

If anyone could please provide some advice it would be greatly appreciated. I have displayed part of the code as follows:

```
won = False

while numberOfGuesses < maxGuesses:
   guess = int(input('What is your guess?: '))
   numberOfGuesses += 1
   if guess < number:
        print('Too low')
   if guess > number:
        print('Too high')
   if guess == number:
        won = True
        break
   print('You have', str(maxGuesses - numberOfGuesses) + ' guesses remaining\n')

if won:
    print('Congratulations!!! You guessed the number in ' + str(numberOfGuesses) + ' tries!')
else:
    print('Game Over!!! You did not guess the correct number, the number was ' + str(number))


f = open('Statistics.txt', 'a')
f.write(str(playerName)+ '|' +str(numberOfGuesses)+'\n')
f.close()
f = open('Statistics.txt', 'r')
print(f.read())
```

Comment: How is that any harder/different than what you've already done?

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In particular, "How do I implement this feature" is discussed as being off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The code exits every time the player wins or loses. Are you expecting to update the Statistics.txt file with the new stat for an existing player? If so, you may have to read the file again and search for the player, retrieve the # of attempts, and determine the win-loss stats. Also like @fooiey stated, you will have to capture win vs. loss to determine the win/loss info. In this case, you will have to update win column and loss column based on the results from current game. Hope this helps.

Comment: a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to accomplish would help no only question answerers but yourself. How are you expecting this to work, and what do you see that is different?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty, simple.
To clarify, if won == True, you want to write "Won" to the line and if won == False, you want to write "Loss" to the line right?

```
win_or_loss = 'Loss'
if won:
    win_or_loss = 'Win'
```

Then you just use this variable when you write to the file

```
f.write(str(playerName)+ '|' + win_or_loss + '|' +str(numberOfGuesses)+'\n')
```

Also, you don't need to wrap playerName in str() since it is already a string.

Comment: Hi @fooiey, thank you so much for your help, this has worked, thanks again, take care.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `playerName` in the mix, I assume you're trying to keep score stats per player.  In that case, I suggest you create a dictionary keyed on player names. The values can be lists of `[numCorrect, totalGuesses]` per player.  You would update `numCorrect` and `totalGuesses` during each player's turn as appropriate.  In the end, you would walk through that dictionary and process the results.

Comment: Dictionary may not work if someone ended the program and came back the next time to try it again. You need to have the win-loss written into the file so it can keep track of stats irrespective of time.

Comment: It would work fine if the program also read the Statistics.txt on start and populated the dictionary.  But we don't have all of OP's code to inform us of the full design intent, do we?

Comment: I totally agree. I think more details about the implementation would have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the logic to implement so you can get the Win/Loss stats.

For each game, you will have the following

Player Name, Win or Loss flag, Total Guesses.

Read statistics file to see if player exists. If player exists, then retrieve the following information:

Player Name, Win Count, Loss Count, Win-Loss Stats, Lowest Number of Guesses

```
* Win Count will be # of times player has won in the past

* Loss Count will be # of times player has lost in the past

* Win-Loss stat will be Win / (Win + Loss). If you want % then x by 100

* Lowest Number of Guesses for the first entry will be numberOfGuesses
```

For all subsequent entries, you need to update the record in the file based on new calculations as shown below.

```
If current game is win, win_count += 1
If current game is loss, loss_count += 1
win_loss stat will remain win_count / (win_count + loss_count)

if numberOfGuesses < lowest_number_of_guesses: lowest_number_of_guesses = numberOfGuesses. 

#you can modify this with walrus option if you use 3.8+
```

Write back this stats to the file. This will keep track of the status for the player and you can use this to keep the stats updated every time the player plays

Since you are going to have a lot of I/O with the above logic, you may want to read the file into memory and calculate this in memory, then write to file as part of normal program exit. One challenge is that the data will be lost if the program abruptly crashes.

Hope this helps you implement a good logic.

I wanted to write this in comments but the max chars exceeded. So put this in the answer comments. I would prefer you write the code as it will help you with the implementation of the logic.